# Going backwards in a ListIterator WITHOUT duplicating the last element that was shown

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been learning Java from scratch and really love it but there is this little problem of mine here I can't wrap my head around it. The following code works, I've tested it and the point is when the user goes backward in the list, the last output should not be duplicated. And here comes my question: why is (!goingForward) points to .next and not the other way around?

```
public static void visit(LinkedList<String> linkedList) {

    ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
    boolean quit = false;
    boolean goingForward = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if(linkedList.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No cities to visit");
    } else {
        printMenu();
    }
    while (!quit) {
        int actions = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        switch (actions) {
            case 0:
                printMenu();
                break;
            case 1:
                if(!goingForward) {
                    if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        listIterator.next();
                    }
                goingForward = true;

                }
                if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.println("Now visiting: " + listIterator.next());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Reached the end of the list");
                    goingForward = false;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(goingForward) {
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                        listIterator.previous();
                    }
                    goingForward = false;
                }
                if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                    System.out.println("Now visiting: " + listIterator.previous());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("We are at the start of the list");
                    goingForward = true;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Thanks for using the app");
                quit = true;
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's to avoid visiting the last city again when changing direction. Try what happens when you remove that logic:

```
public class ListIteratorDemo {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    LinkedList<String> cities = new LinkedList<>();
    cities.add("A");
    cities.add("B");
    cities.add("C");
    visit(cities);
  }

  public static void visit(LinkedList<String> linkedList) {

    ListIterator<String> listIterator = linkedList.listIterator();
    boolean quit = false;
    //    boolean goingForward = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    if(linkedList.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No cities to visit");
    }
    else {
      printMenu();
    }

    while(!quit) {
      int actions = scanner.nextInt();
      scanner.nextLine();
      switch(actions) {
        case 0: {
          printMenu();
          break;
        }
        case 1: {
          //          if(!goingForward) {
          //            if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
          //              listIterator.next();
          //            }
          //            goingForward = true;
          //          }

          if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Now visiting: " + listIterator.next());
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("Reached the end of the list");
            //            goingForward = false;
          }
          break;
        }
        case 2: {
          //          if(goingForward) {
          //            if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
          //              listIterator.previous();
          //            }
          //            goingForward = false;
          //          }

          if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println("Now visiting: " + listIterator.previous());
          }
          else {
            System.out.println("We are at the start of the list");
            //            goingForward = true;
          }
          break;
        }
        case 3: {
          System.out.println("Thanks for using the app");
          quit = true;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static void printMenu() {
    System.out.println("0=menu, 1=next, 2=previous, 3=quit");
  }
}
```

I suppose it is to teach about the ListIterator cursors positions:

[image]

About your question: If you type 1 (forward) and were previously going backwards (!goingForward), the cursor will be to the left of the last visitied city. It has to be shifted to the right of the last visited city in order to avoid visiting it again when moving forward (calling next).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm really struggling with this concept as I don't understand that case 1 is the option to go forward, however the "if" statement says (!goingForward) call listiterator.next .... why calling .next and not .previous? let's say I just put out element 1 so the iterator is between element 1 and 2, now going backward but I'm calling .next, why not .previous? the logic seems reverse to me.

Comment: I tried to explain that in my last paragraph. The `goingForward` variable is used to save the direction of the last move. The if statements check if the current move changed direction (compared to the last move).

Comment: Imagine being between 1 and 2. Then move backwards: You visit 1 and are now between 0 and 1. Now you go forward again. This is the switch case 1: Skip with next over element 1, and then next again to visit 2, landing between 2 and 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It wasn't you, it was me. Your explanation is spotless it just took me some time to process it as I was thinking of the process backwards. At the end of each switch I set goingForward to true of false and that sets up the whole process. Thank you again for your kind help! I'm heading to learn about BinaryTrees and after that Generics. It is an awesome journey, love it!

Comment: Glad to hear :) Please accept the answer if it solved your question. Good luck!